# Evaluating the limit of $2 n^2 + (-1)^n7n$

Tags: limits

I'm trying to evaluate the following limit. $$\lim_{n\to \infty} (2n^2 + (-1)^n7n)$$

When I plug this into WolframAlpha, it suggests factoring out $n$ and using the product rule as follows: $$\lim_{n\to \infty}n\lim_{n\to \infty}( 2n + (-1)^n7)$$

However, my professor has mentioned that this cannot be done, since $\lim_{n\to \infty}n=\infty$, and the product rule cannot be applied to such cases. i.e., if $\lim_{n\to \infty}a_n=a$ and $\lim_{n\to \infty}b_n=b$, then$\lim_{n\to \infty}a_n\cdot b_n=a\cdot b$ if and only if $a\neq \pm\infty$ and $b\neq \pm\infty$. Who is wrong in this case, is it my professor of WolframAlpha?

Comment: Your professor is right

Comment: If you try to collect the factor $n^2$...then you evaluate the stuff left inside the brackets

Answer (score 1, accepted):

However, if you factor out $n^2$, you get
$$
\begin{align}
\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(2n^2+(-1)^n7n\right)
&=\overbrace{\ \lim_{n\to\infty}n^2\vphantom{\frac7n}\ }^\infty\overbrace{\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(2+\frac{(-1)^n7}n\right)}^2\\
&=\infty
\end{align}
$$
and this does show the limit is $\infty$.

Answer (score 1):

Your professor is right, Wolfram does not take convergence of the limit into account properly.

Comment: So if this method is incorrect, could you use the Ratio Test of Limits to show that $\lim_{n\to \infty}a_n=\infty$?